# How to improve my MongoDB structure?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, database

## The question

I am creating a MongoDB structure with mongoose's Schema.

The purpose of the website is to store tutorials (*Article*) related to a *Component*. A *Component* is in a *Category* and comes from one or more *Supplier*. I come from SQL database so I am not sure of the structure I did for this NoSQL database..

Is there **missing** informations? Is the structure **right**?

## Actual structure

### Article

```
* title : String
* [ components : Component ]
* abstract : String (160- chars)
* content : String (markdown)
* [ langages : Langages ]
* created : Date
* [ files : 
  - path : String 
  - description : String ]
* by : User
* [ edited : User ]
```

### Supplier

```
* name : String
* serial : String (10- chars)
* country : Country
* adress : String
* city : String
* score : Number
* [ components : 
  - component : Component
  - price : Number ]
```

### Country *Should store?*

```
* name : String (China)
* serial : String (ZH)
* [ suppliers : Supplier ]
```

### Component

```
* name : String (ex : Bluetooth slave)
* reference : String (ex : HC-06 )
* [ suppliers : Supplier ]
* [ categories : Category ]
* [ images : String ]
```

### Category

```
* name : String
* description : String
* [ component : Component ]
```

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB is a document database, and is very flexible, in that you can structure your documents any way you choose! This will feel very different than the SQL way of doing things.

From your questions, there is no "right" and if you have an ID from one document to another, the information is "complete" as well. The car example for SQL and Not-SQL DBs is that SQL is like an automatic transmission that does a lot for you, and NoSQL is a manual transmission. You can get more performance, but you have to tune it more as well.

Do you have any one-to-one relationships? If yes, just make them the same document.

If you're always pulling a tree (Component + Categories + Suppliers) the same way, maybe just make it a single document! Easy on the reads, and more work on the updates. From your example, just embed the Category and Countries - they are essentially just Strings.

Don't be afraid of doubling up data if that helps you get performant reads, and a more simplied structure. Likely, you'll be reading a **lot** more than you'll be writing anyway. And you'll be creating/updating some things (Articles) a **lot** more than you'll be updating Suppliers, Categories, etc.

There are lots more things you will try, and your data might change often. This is counted as a strength of NoSQL DBs! You don't need to manage a schema, and old documents just won't have that new field available. (Of course, if you want all that old data to have said new field, you have a lot of updating to do!)

As a final note, if you're willing to restructure all your data, just use SQL because you already understand it, and pick a nice ORM like [Bookshelf](http://bookshelfjs.org/) or [Sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/), or just some query access via [Knex](http://knexjs.org/). Make your data access work for you! There is a chance a document store isn't a fit for your app, and if you are looking to get something done (rather than learn about Mongo), you will have better success just using SQL.